# Is Sulfuric hydrofluoric acid a real thing?

Tags: acid-base

I saw a video on social media of a person disappearing into air when exposed to Sulfuric hydrofluoric acid vapours. I don't have much knowledge in chemistry. Is this possible combination.

Comment: I saw a video of a dude made of liquid metal, he used to stab people with swords made of his own hands.

Comment: Yes, it's a real compound commonly known as [Fluorosulfuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorosulfuric_acid). Not the strongest among superacids, but is definitely corrosive. However, that thing you saw would be called a witchery 500 years ago; these days it's called BS of fake news (as most of the social media is:) ).

Answer (score 4):

There is an actual compound called [fluorosulfuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorosulfuric_acid), $\ce{HSO3F}$ as mentioned by @andselisk. It is one of the strongest acid known. It hydrolyzes slowly to sulfuric acid and hydrofluoric acid. It is highly toxic and corrosive in nature. If it comes in contact with human skin, it will eat your skin right away leaving no trace and so it will help you to disappear happily. Anyway, jokes aside, fluorosulfuric acid disappearing people is absolute nonsense. Don't try any experiment with fluorosulfuric acid. It is highly toxic and I highly recommend to stay away from it.